# Passing vars in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have followed the following link and implemented the example for my own script.

[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-before-upload-image)

I have 8 file upload inputs followed by a img tag of it's own

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg" onchange="readURL(this,1);"/>
<img id="imagediv1" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

Now the javascript I modified

```
function readURL(input,cnum) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var cimage = 'imagediv'+cnum;
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#cimage")
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }     }
}
```

I did an alert(); within the javascript and the cimage var does get created properly. 
However, the img doesn't change as it does in the example. I did try manually creating a function for each imagediv#, and it works fine.

Am I missing something within the javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take "cimage" out of the quotes and instead concatenate it to "#":

```
$("#"+cimage)
```

Or, better yet, don't bother with creating the `cimage` variable at all and just do this:

```
$("#imagediv" + cnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector:

```
$("#" + cimage).attr("src", e.target.result).width(150).height(200);
```

Your selector `$("#cimage")` is looking for an element with `id="cimage"`.